# How to fix horizontal scroll on iOS (Mobile)

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have a weird issue that bugs me. I've setup a project with html/css that enables horizontal scrolling. This works fine for PC/Android but doesn't work on iOS unless I drag at the edge of the screen (which takes me to the previous or next page visited) and drag back again. When doing this I'm allowed to scroll perfectly until the scroll stops. If I want to scroll again I have to repeat the drag gesture. It's like the scrolling area won't get focus or something. Snippets of the attempt (HTML):

```
<div class="scrollable">
    <div class="scrollable-content">
        <div id="tournaments-horizontal">
            <div class="tournament-h-container"></div>
            <div class="tournament-h-container"></div>
            <div class="tournament-h-container"></div>
            <div class="tournament-h-container"></div>
            <div class="tournament-h-container"></div>
            <div class="tournament-h-container"></div>
            <div class="tournament-h-container"></div>
            <div class="tournament-h-container"></div>
            <div class="tournament-h-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:
http://pastebin.com/aUsQQUjm

I would really appreciate if someone knew something about this. Again, to repeat the "solution" for iOS:

1. Load the page
2. Try to scroll in the scrolling area (nothing happens)
3. Drag at either edge of the screen in Safari (you will see the  previous/next page the browser has queued) but don't drag all the way. Just get a glimpse of that page and then drag back to the current page
4. Now you can scroll as expected (until the scrollbar disappears).
5. Repeat step 3-4

(Screwed up the code tag so I decided to link to a pastebin instead).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you be so kind to flag my answer as the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer did not solve the problem at hand. As it turned out it was AngularJS directive "ngTouch" who messed with it. ng-swipe was taking control over the element. As your answer probably helps with "normal" CSS issues it might be correct so I dont know if I should answer my own question or mark yours as correct

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: What would you suggest then? I mean yours is absolutely correct but I made a mistake in not answering my own question when I found the actual issue to my problem (which is completely out of context anyway since I didn't even mention Angular in the question)

Comment: We might have to open a new thread for that question ;)

Answer (score 12):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.scrolling-element {
    overflow-x: scroll; /* Must be 'scroll' not 'auto' */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" was the magic. Worked with "overflow-x: auto;" also. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that on iPad when touching some `div`s (like `<table>`) I couldn't scroll horizontally, neither zoom-in/out

I fixed by calling `event.stopPropagation()` of the `touchmove` event on those `div`s

The way that I did was identifying those `div`s like

```
<table class="fix-ipad-scroll"> 
    ...
</table>
```

so I could run this code:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('fix-ipad-scroll');

if(elements.length == 0){
   console.error(
     "Ops, no element with the 'fix-ipad-scroll' " +
     "class found, you need to fix that"
   );
}
   
for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
   elements.item(i).addEventListener("touchmove", (ev) => {
      ev.stopPropagation();
   });
}
```